# Windows Phone Equivalent of a WinRT ContentControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, contentcontrol

I am trying to port a custom content control class from a WinRT app to a Windows Phone 8 app, but I cannot figure out exactly how to accomplish it. I essentially want to port something like the following:

MenuPanel.cs

```
public sealed class MenuPanel : ContentControl
{
    #region ContentVisibility

    /// <summary>
    /// ContentVisibility Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ContentVisibility",
            typeof(Visibility),
            typeof(MenuPanel),
            new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible, null));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the ContentVisibility property
    /// </summary>
    public Visibility ContentVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ContentVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    ... Lots more, but truncated for brevity
}
```

Generics.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Expansion.WinRT.Controls">

    <Style TargetType="local:MenuPanel">
        <Setter Property="ContentVisibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Property="EnableVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MenuPanel">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#33FFFFFF" BorderThickness="16" CornerRadius="1" />
                        <Border BorderBrush="#4CFFFFFF" BorderThickness="8" CornerRadius="1" Margin="4" />
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" Background="#26FFFFFF" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="1" Margin="7" Padding="3">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ContentVisibility}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                                <Button 
                                    Name="EnableButton"
                                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding EnableVisibility}"
                                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                    Content="+"
                                    FontSize="40" 
                                    Padding="0,-10,0,0" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Width="70" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
    ...
    <local:MenuPanel Name="MainMenuPanel" Width="520" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="StartMenu" Visibility="Visible">
                <Button Name="NewGameButton" Content="New Game" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontSize="30" />
                <Button Name="LoadGameButton" Content="Load Game" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontSize="30" />
                <Button Name="OptionsButton" Content="Options" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontSize="30" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </local:MenuPanel>
    ...
```

I took a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.105).aspx but it didn't help much.

Comment: What exact problem do you get porting the code?

Comment: Well, it I try to bring it over exactly how it is in the WinRT version, and just fix the namespaces to my WP8 version, for some reason, it claims that MenuPanel is not part of local: in the generics.xaml. So it won't compile.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Seems I need to use clr-namespace instead of using in the xml namespace part.